# Generating prime p where p-1 is hard to factor

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

This paper: [An Interactive Identification Scheme Based on Discrete Logarithms and Factoring](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-46877-3_6.pdf) requires generating primes $p$ with the following special format:

> We choose $p$ with the property that $p - 1$ has at least two large prime factors, so that the factorization of $p - 1$ is hard to recover.

Two questions that arise:

1. How to formally define that a number has at least two large prime factors?
2. Are there infinitely many such numbers, and are they easy to find?

I wrote a simple Python 3 program to test this (requires `gmpy2` and `secrets` modules). Admittedly, it doesn't prove anything, but it gives me some reassurance that such primes are abundant.

It runs 100 times, generates two random 512-bit primes $s$ and $t$, and tests whether $p = j\times s \times t + 1$ is a prime, for a small $j$ in $\{1,\ldots,10000\}$.

While the format of $p$ in the program is more restricted than what the paper defines, the program runs quite fast, and is able to generate the required prime all the time (this holds at least for all the executions I did).

```
from gmpy2 import next_prime, is_prime
from secrets import randbits

for i in range(100):
    s = next_prime(randbits(512))
    t = next_prime(randbits(512))
    for j in range(1, 10000):
        p = j * s * t + 1
        if (is_prime(p)):
            print(i, j)
            break
```

**Edit:** One way to formalize item 1 is to require that $p-1$ has at most $C$ prime factors, where $C$ is a constant. [This MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27553/9544) states that it follows from the [sieve theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_theory) that there is a small constant C (like 6). Does anyone know the exact result?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I would also use this same approach. Pick large primes $s$ and $t$, and search for primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{st}$. [Dirichlet's theorem of primes in an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) then guarantees that there are infinitely many primes $p$ of this form. Mind you, the extra factor $j$ may become quite large. May be a clever choice of $(s,t)$ helps? I don't know.

Comment: If $\ p\ $ is an arbitary very large prime, $\ p-1\ $ is likely to be difficult to be factored completely. This makes simple primality proofs based on the factorization of $\ p-1\ $ difficult.

Comment: @Peter: Is there any result telling "how" likely is it difficult to be factored?

Comment: I am not aware of an estimation how likely the second largest prime factor is "large". We could however estimate the probability that the number has no prime factor with , lets say, less than $50$ digits without beging prime. You can use that the probability that a huge random number has no prime factor below $10^{49}$ , is $$0.0049763\cdots $$ which is about $1:201$

Comment: @Peter: It's OK that $p-1$ has small factors, insofar as it also has at least two large factors.

Comment: You already found a method to generate such a prime , hence $2.$ is basically done.$1.$ depends on what we consider to be "large"

Comment: @Peter: My method doesn't guarantee anything. Say, replacing 512 with 8192 or larger number, while fixing 10000. Is it guaranteed that there will be an output at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104807/discussion-between-peter-and-m-s-dousti).

Comment: To make it run a bit faster, you can only need to run through the loop for even $j$, since for odd $j$, $j \times s \times t + 1$ is even.

Comment: @Paul, while that might help superficially, presumably `is_prime` will return extremely quickly on even numbers and take much longer on average, so the gains would be extremely small.